# Error in FB.login() phonegap facebook plugin

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, sencha-touch, facebook-javascript-sdk

When i run fb.login() in an ios 6 device using the account setted in Settings/facebook i get the following

```
operation couldn't be completed (com.facebook.sdk error 2)
```

in ios 5 the app works perfectly, the problem is the native login

help please ! this is my code

this is the facebook init

```
   this.appId = appId;
    var me = this;

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
                                  try {

                                  FB.init({ appId: "294003447379425", status: true, cookie: true, nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });

                                  } catch (e) {
                                  console.log(e);
                                  }
                                  }, false);


    if (!this.appId) {
        Ext.Logger.error('No Facebook Application ID set.');
        return;
    }



    var me = this;
    me.hasCheckedStatus = false;


    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function() {
        // This event can be fired as soon as the page loads which may cause undesired behaviour, so we wait
        // until after we've specifically checked the login status.
        if (me.hasCheckedStatus) {
            me.fireEvent('logout');
        }
    });

    // Get the user login status from Facebook.
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

        me.fireEvent('loginStatus');

        clearTimeout(me.fbLoginTimeout);
        me.hasCheckedStatus = true;

        if (response.status == 'connected') {
            me.fireEvent('connected');


        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('CinePass.view.Main'));


        } else {
            me.fireEvent('unauthorized');
            console.log('noconectado');

            Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('CinePass.view.LoggedOut'));
        }
    });

    // We set a timeout in case there is no response from the Facebook `init` method. This often happens if the
    // Facebook application is incorrectly configured (for example if the browser URL does not match the one
    // configured on the Facebook app.)
    me.fbLoginTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        me.fireEvent('loginStatus');
        me.fireEvent('exception', {
            type: 'timeout',
            msg: 'The request to Facebook timed out.'
        });
        Ext.Msg.alert('CinePass', 'Existe un problema con Facebook, se iniciará la aplicación sin conexión a Facebook.', Ext.emptyFn);
         Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('CinePass.view.Main'));
    }, me.fbTimeout);
```

this is the login

```
            FB.login(
                     function(response) {
                     if (response.session) {
                      alert(response.session);

                     } else {
                  alert(response.session);
                     }
                     },
                     { scope: "email,user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,friends_interests" }
                     );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the same problem and took me few days to figure this out, there are a number of reasons:

1) The first time you launch your app, if you deny the "Do you allow this app to use your facebook permission", you'll get this error, what you need to do is, go to Setting > General > Facebook > turn on your app OR go to Setting > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy (this will reset and ask you the "Do you allow this app to use your facebook permission" again for all app.

2) Slow/No Internet can caused the error

3) Create your certificate again, and go to build.phonegap.com, create a new key for IOS and change the IOS key (This works for me, I have no idea how it works but it does, I notice a significant app file size increase after i use a new IOS Key)

4) If your app is in sand box mode, and your IOS current Facebook account is not an app tester you'll get the error too. I just disable the sand box mode and it works, make sure your Facebook App Setting has the correct bundle ID, if your app is still under developement, put 0 to app store ID.